# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to generate a simple  matplotlib figure as per below code in pycharm.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.linspace(0, 5, 11)
y = x ** 2


fig = plt.figure()
axes1 = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
axes2 = fig.add_axes([0.2,0.5,0.4,0.3])

axes1.plot(x,y)
axes2.plot(y,x)

axes1.set_xlabel('X_1 label')
axes1.set_ylabel('Y_1 label')
axes1.set_title('Title_1')

axes2.set_xlabel('X_2 label')
axes2.set_ylabel('Y_2 label')
axes2.set_title('Title_2')
```

I am getting an error

```
/home/lk/anaconda3/envs/pycharm/bin/python "/home/lk/Desktop/Python Exps/pycharm/tr.py"
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path '/run/user/1000/snap.pycharm-community', please create it with 0700 permissions.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What is the meaning of this error and how can I make it go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create a directory using:

```
$ mkdir -p /run/user/1000/snap.pycharm-community
```

And change it's permissions like this:

```
$ chmod 0700 /run/user/1000/snap.pycharm-community
```

Alternatively you could set your environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`:

```
$ export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/your/dir
```

[Source and more information on the topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory)

Comment: `/run/user/1000` is typically created by systemd, *already owned by uid 1000*, when the user with that UID logs in. There should not be a need for any further privileged invocations.