# StandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 0...How to solve on fedora

Tags: python, linux, terminal, runtime, fedora

> QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 0
>   Warning: found huge icon. The icon data may be ill-encoded. (2000 x 2000)
>   Warning: found huge icon. The icon data may be ill-encoded. (2000 x 2000)
>   Warning: found huge icon. The icon data may be ill-encoded. (2000 x 2000)
>   Warning: found huge icon. The icon data may be ill-encoded. (2000 x 2000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try out setting the environment variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to your path, using either

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/run/user/1000
```

or

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

before calling your program.
Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55210689/5114342.

Comment: This doesn't work in new versions and beta versions

Comment: FYI: `XDG` stands for  `Cross Desktop Group`. The term is used by [freedesktop.org specifications aiming interoperability](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/). One of these is : [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) describing the use of variable `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.